# Integrating a set of measure 0 but unbounded values

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am currently working on learning some measure theory, and I recently came across this question, posed to me in my book:

Show that if $f \geq 0$ and $\int_{\Omega} f d\mu = 0$, then $f=0$ almost everywhere

If I assume the additional condition that $0 \leq f \leq M$, this is an easy question, but my question is this: Let's say that I had $f = g + h$ such that $g$ is some nice function on a set $ E \subset \Omega$ of nonzero measure, and $h$ is a function such that the values of $h$ are all infinite but $\mu(E^c) = 0$, where $E^c \subset \Omega$. Would the value of $\int_{E^c} h d\mu = 0$ still? Or does the idea of assigning infinite values not make sense in this case? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I believe you have to accept the standard definition $0\cdot \infty = 0$.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Now that you say that I remember seeing that somewhere else, but they didn't define it in the book. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral of a function $f\colon \Omega \to [0,\infty]$ is usually defined as the supremum of all $\int_\Omega \varphi d\mu$, where $\varphi$ is any simple function with $\varphi \leq f$.

I think that usually simple functions are only allowed to take finite values (i.e. in $\mathbb{R}$), hence the problem with $0\cdot \infty$ wouldn't occur here. So, if $f$ is almost everywhere zero, all the $\int_\Omega \varphi d\mu$ are zero and the supremum as well.